# Rails 3 CanCan nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Have a nested resource as such

```
class Dealer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :vehicles
end
```

and

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealer
end
```

below are my routes.

```
  resources :dealers do
    resources :vehicles,           :except => [:index]
  end
  resources :vehicles, :only => [:index]
```

looking at the [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources) at the github page for cancan I did the following:

```
class VehiclesController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :dealer
  load_and_authorize_resource :vehicle, :through => :dealer

  def index
    @vehicles = Vehicle.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @vehicles }
    end
  end
end
```

but now when the admin tries to go to the index page with the abilities:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can     :manage, :all
  end
end
```

I get

```
Couldn't find Dealer with id=
```

what do i need to change for admin to still be able to do all the actions and yet have others be checked before they can do any action.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that he is not authorized to this action. The problem is that CanCan tries to fetch an instance of dealer to load all its vehicles and you have not provided a :dealer_id within params[:dealer_id]. Cancan assumes you would be loading only dealer's vehicles in this controller because you used an load_and_authorieze :through. This authorization should be used within Dealers::VehiclesController.

As long as you only loading vehicles just use load_and_authorize_resource :vehicle. And because load_and_authorize will set `@vehicles` for you within the before filter there is also no need to load the vehicles explicitly with `Vehicle.all`.

load_and_authorize is just a convenient method and it assumes some defaults. Once you will come to a point where you have some more complex use case. It will be time to throw away this method and just use CanCan's `authorize!`, `can?` and a properly configured `Vehicle .accessible_by` (for listing) methods.

Comment: I did explore the authorize! but i am not that good with rails yet to implement that fully myself. My goals is as follows: Admin manage all with being able to create vehicles for any dealer. Dealer Manage its own Vehicles and be able to modify its own Vehicles etc. Should only be able to create for its own dealership as well. So how do i go about it?

Comment: How does the Dealer relates to the User model?

Answer (score 0):

When using `load_and_authorize_resource :vehicle, through: :dealer` it expects to receive a `dealer_id` in the request in order to authorize the dealer.

Since you use `except: :index` in your routes `dealer_id` will not be automatically included in the request.

If you don't want to authorize the dealer in the index action you can do something like this (taken from [Can Can wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions#choosing-actions-on-nested-resources))

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource :post
  load_and_authorize_resource :through => :post

  skip_authorize_resource :only => :show  
  skip_authorize_resource :post, :only => :show
end
```

Comment: It is still giving me the same error. So unfortunately this is not working.